# Best Comet/Push technology for Java/Tomcat server?

Tags: java, tomcat, push, comet

I'm currently working on a web application that might need to "push" information to the client  and I was wondering what are the best ways to implement this on a Java/Tomcat environment. I looked at web sockets but it seems that browser support is still somewhat lacking. I'm currently looking at the org.apache.catalina.CometProcessor interface, but I'd like to know if anyone has any good recommendations. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you considered icefaces ?

http://www.icefaces.org/main/ajax-java/ajaxpush.iface

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem to solve in an Javascript/Java (without Tomcat) environment. I used long polls as the base technology.

- The client polls the server
- The server holds the connection for a maximum amount of time (20 seconds in my case)

  - If an event is fired on the server side, all client connection handlers are notified (a messeage is sent to the client) and the long poll ends
  - If nothing happens, the long poll ends with an empty message
- After the long poll connection is colsed, it starts again.

In my case I had to take care about some proxies which had problems with long opened http connections without data transfer. So I chooses 20 seconds as the maximum amount of time to keep an http transfer open. In combination with http keep-alive, you can also reduce the number of connections that are opened from a single client while polling.

Hope that helps.